# Can't resolve all parameters for MyApp

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Sorry if this seems like a duplicate to the other questions since they didn't help solve my issue. Can someone help me with this? I've tried removing the parameters one by one, but still no good.

```
Can't resolve all parameters for MyApp: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

import { GlobalService } from '../services/global-service';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { Insomnia } from '@ionic-native/insomnia';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp{

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, private global : GlobalService,
              private file: File, private insomnia: Insomnia){}
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { GlobalService } from '../services/global-service';
import { UserService } from '../services/user-service';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FileTransfer } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
import { Insomnia } from '@ionic-native/insomnia';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
import { MusicControls } from '@ionic-native/music-controls';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [...],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp
  ],
  providers: [
    Platform,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Insomnia,
    File,
    FileTransfer,
    Network,
    MusicControls,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    GlobalService,
    UserService,
    { provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: HammerGestureConfig }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

services/global-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as SoundFont from 'soundfont-player';
import * as Firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';

import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalService {..}
```

Can't seem to find the root cause at all for my error. I'm using Ionic 3.9.2, Angular Core 5.2.9, Node 6.10.2. Is it possible that there may be something wrong with my node_modules or some of my configs?

Comment: Are you missing Platform as a provider?

Comment: Added it, still the same error. @SimplyGed

Comment: And you added it as an import? Can you update your question to show your changes please?

Comment: Yup added it as import. same error. see above edit @SimplyGed

Comment: If you remove the the parameters one by one, which one is giving the error?

Comment: All. Can't seem to recognize the classes I imported. Did I miss something in configs or node_modules? @SimplyGed

Answer (score 3):

You're not providing `Platform` as a provider.

```
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { GlobalService } from '../services/global-service';
import { UserService } from '../services/user-service';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FileTransfer } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
import { Insomnia } from '@ionic-native/insomnia';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
import { MusicControls } from '@ionic-native/music-controls';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [...],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp
  ],
  providers: [
    Platform,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Insomnia,
    File,
    FileTransfer,
    Network,
    MusicControls,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    GlobalService,
    UserService,
    { provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: HammerGestureConfig }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Simply put `Can't resolve all parameters for MyApp: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).` mean's that all the parameters your app's constructor is expecting isn't being met.

EDIT

Maybe you're missing app-root selector on your `App` component.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

import { GlobalService } from '../services/global-service';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { Insomnia } from '@ionic-native/insomnia';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp{

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, private global : GlobalService,
              private file: File, private insomnia: Insomnia){}
}
```

Comment: You said in your other comment that you have imported `Platform` but you haven't updated the import in the answer. You've added it as a provider but not imported it into the class. Can you check and update your question please.

Comment: It's not that you're missing `selector: 'app-root',` on your App Component? - Updated answer

Comment: Tried it. still no good. tried also adding `selector: 'ion-app'` (it's an Ionic project), nada.

Comment: After doing some research, don't suppose you have a circular dependency in the `Global Service`?

Comment: start by removing all the parameters from the `MyApp constructor` and take it from there

Answer (score 0):

## did you edit your index.html ?

If you did, undo the changes or make sure the order of the build files are `polyfills.js, vendor.js and main.js` cause i did try to reproduce this issue.